# {historische-zeitschrift} footnote back references to each chapter

Tags: biblatex, chapters, back-referencing

Using "historische-zeitschrift" (similar to the other -dw styles) as biblatex style, the back references within the footnotes always refer to the first appearence in the whole book. I'd like to change it in a way, that it only refers to to first appearence *within* a chapter.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
 bibencoding=utf8,
 style=historische-zeitschrift,
 backref=true,
 backend=biber]
{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Example text\footcite{book1} another text\footcite{book2}    
\chapter{Two}
Example text\footcite{book2} another text\footcite{book2} another \footcite{book1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

delivers footnotes in the following style:

**[page Chapter One]**

1 full record book 1

2 full record book 2

**[page Chapter Two]**

1 short record book 2 (see ref. 2)  *<--- here it should give a full record as it's a new chapter!*

2 short record book 2 (see ref. 2)  *<--- here it should give a short record (see ref. 1)!*

3 short record book 1 (see ref. 1)   *<--- here it should give a full record as it's the first appearence in Chapter Two!*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

You have to tell `biblatex` to restart the citations with the option `citereset=chapter`. Also the option `ibidtracker=false` is needed if you want short references instead of "Ibid."

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[
 bibencoding=utf8,
 style=historische-zeitschrift,
 citereset=chapter,
 ibidtracker=false,
 backref=true,
 backend=biber]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Example text\footcite{vangennep} another text\footcite{piccato}
\chapter{Two}
Example text\footcite{piccato} another text\footcite{piccato} another \footcite{vangennep}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]